# Get the int at the end in a string using power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

```
Tom1Jerry02 --> 02,
abcd0asdf001 --> 001,
qwerty1 --> 1
```

I am new to Powershell and wanted to know: how I can extract the integers at the end of the string from the above sample using power shell?

**Edit:**

These are 3 separate strings
`Tom1Jerry02`, `abcd0asdf001` and `qwerty1`. I need a solution suitable for those kind of strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PowerShell you're likely to find many different ways to do the same thing.  Here's a way to do this as one-liner:

```
PS> 'Tom1Jerry02','abcd0asdf001','qwerty1' | Foreach {if ($_ -match '(\d+)$') {$matches[1]}}
02
001
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> $a =  "Tom1Jerry02 --> 02", "abcd0asdf001 --> 001", "qwerty1 --> 1"
PS> foreach ($s in $a) {
>> $b = $s -Match "(\d+)$"
>> write-output $matches[1]
>> }
>>
```

Output:

```
02
001
1
```

Comment: If I need to avoid the true in the output, what needs to be done?

Comment: @TJK Just assign the result of the match to a variable.  See updated solution.

Comment: For noobs like me it would be worth noting that $matches is an automatically generated array